# CAS with SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler no redirecting correctly

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-security, cas

I'm trying solve a problem using CAS with Spring Security, when I do a link to another url that use to the same CAS Server.

I tried change the SimpleURLAuthenticationSuccess by SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler like in this [link](http://roguecoder.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/jasig-cas-spring-security-and-bookmarking/#respond) but still not working.

To show better my scenario is:

I have two applications running in the same CAS Server.
When I access the application 1, then I goes to the CAS Server.
After logIn I access the context of application normally.

The problem occur when I try access application 2 through the following link

```
<a href="/applicationB/pages/motors/1"/>
```

I'm redirected to CAS and CAS redirect me to /applicationB, context of application.

According with this [link](http://roguecoder.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/jasig-cas-spring-security-and-bookmarking/), I simply should change the bean SimpleURLAuthenticationSuccess by SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler

**Edited**

I saw that maybe the solution isn't use SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler, because, the CasAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and this class have the following method:

```
/**
 * Sets the strategy used to handle a successful authentication.
 * By default a {@link SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler} is used.
 */
public void setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler) {
    Assert.notNull(successHandler, "successHandler cannot be null");
    this.successHandler = successHandler;
}
```

Comment: Solved !!! The solution stay here [link](http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/remember-target-url-with-spring.html) . Please, if possible upvote this issue on spring-security to help us to extends the funcionality of CasAuthenticationProvider, the link [link](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2188)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !!! The solution stay in this [article](http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/remember-target-url-with-spring.html) . Please, if possible upvote this issue on spring-security to help us to extends the funcionality of CasAuthenticationProvider, the [link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2188)